# Create image from Canvas with AVIF image format

Tags: javascript, html, avif

AVIF a very promising image format/codec which based on the sample is far better than JPEG.
My question is how do you create a AVIF image from a Canvas?

So instead of JPEG, something like:

```
canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {}, "image/avif", 1.0)
```

Is there a polyfill or something to make it work in the browser (encoding image part)?

Reference:
https://github.com/Kagami/avif.js

Answer (score 5):

Currently no browsers support creation of an AVIF from a canvas, but that should change soon.

- [Chrome can already consume AVIF images](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=960620), so should be able to generate them from canvas soon.
- [Firefox will add AVIF support in one of the upcoming Firefox releases.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1682995) (likely 87 or 88)

Comment: thanks for this answer. in the meantime, what are the options for server-side conversion of PNG/JPG to AVIF?

Comment: Sadly, Firefox 86 will not support AVIF yet (issues with colors).

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to my attention. Updated the answer to reflect the current status.